# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Making REST API Call to send data from marketing cloud to External

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

I have coupon details in marketing cloud . Once email is sent out of Marketing cloud via journey,i need to send email sent date to external . Post journey acitivty i'm planning to trigger ssjs activity automation to send data.

I have data in Coupon DE which holds coupon email sent date. Date has to be sent to external system which runs using REST API .

1. I have created API Package & got (Client Id/Client Secret/REST API URl)
2. Created a SSJS script Activity in automation studio to send data
3. I have written SSJS to fetch the records from data extension which has to be sent to external system

I need these the DE Data to be sent external system & update  date in external .I'm not aware of the script to configure data sending part & API part . If anyone has sent data from Marketing cloud to external via APIs please share your thoughts .

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");
var CouponDE = DataExtension.Init("CouponDE");
//var fields = CouponDE.Fields.Retrieve();
//var data = CouponDE.Rows.Retrieve();
var filter = {Property:"start_date",SimpleOperator:"greaterThanOrEqual",Value:"2020-06-25"};
var data = birthdayDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter);
var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v2/token';//enterprise 2.0 account
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = {
  "grant_type":"client_credentials",
  "client_id":"YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  "client_secret":"YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
  "account_id":"YOUR_MID"
};
var authRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
var statusCode = authRequest["StatusCode"];
var response = authRequest["Response"][0];
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).accessToken;

url = "need to check ";
url += "need to check";
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
//not sure how to process from here
try {

  var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
  result = Stringify(result).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
  log.Rows.Add({"Message": "result: " + result});

} catch (e) {

  e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')
  log.Rows.Add({"Message": "error: " + e});

}
</script>
```

Comment: Your sample code looks like a mixture of scripts, but fundamentally building up to making some sort of API call to SFMC itself, rather than to an external service. Are you wanting to make a post to an external service or Salesforce Marketing Cloud. If SFMC's the endpoint, you have a mixture of the legacy authorisation workflow and the newer client credentials workflow that uses Tennant Specific Subdomains, returns an "access_token", rather than an "accessToken". You're also referring to a log and birthdayDE that you've not initialized.

Comment: I'm trying to post to external service from marketing cloud .

 It's not birthdaydE ,its CouponDE which i need to extract data from . I 'll make required change for those line which involves birthday DE & Log DE  .

After extracting the DE data(Coupon data) , what needs to be configured in SSJS script  activity to send data to external service. i have the external service endpoint & my API package client id & client secret as well. 

But i'm not sure how to establish the connection in SSSJ script to send data from marketing cloud .